# Getting error while deploying PieCloudDB

Tags: installation, deployment

When installing PieCloudDB on KVM, it prompts that foundationdb is incompatible with the cc container and cannot be deployed. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please provide text information as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying with kvm, the CPU type needs to be selected as "host". If you select "kvm32" or "kvm64", there will be an instruction set incompatibility problem.

Try `cat/proc/cpuinfo` to view cpu information, PieCloudDB requires AVX instruction set, if your CPU itself does not support it, you will also encounter illegal instruction errors.